# VHDLタイミング定数について教えてください。

Tags: vhdl

VHDL初心者です。
下記の記述例をみて勉強中です。
http://kivantium.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/02/25/232858

state=1 の receiving において
elsif counter=1500 then
とありますがビットの中間で受信データを読み取るためには
32MHz/(9600x2)=1666
にするべきだと思うのですが、なぜ1500にされたのか
教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくですが、パルス幅がありますので、ぴったりど真ん中にする必要は無いのだと思います。